Is "to Fender's amazement" a typo in Lords and Ladies by Terry Pratchett?
In my edition of Lords and Ladies by Terry Pratchett, there's a curious name on page 121 (Corgi publishing, 2013 edition. Kirby illustrated version; ISBN: 978-0-552-16752-9. As far as I can tell, there's no other use of this name in the book.
The setting is that Ridcully, Ponder Stibbons, the Bursar and the Librarian are travelling to Lancre on a stagecoach to attend the wedding of Verence and Magrat. They are held-up by the highwaydwarf Giamo Casanunda and  convince him to travel with them. Ridcully invites Casanunda to play Cripple Mr Onion and loses badly, forcing Ridcully to pay up...
Now here's the passage containing the name, with it bolded:

Ridcully sighed and to Fender's amazement produced a bag of coins from some inner recess

As far as I can tell Fender should be Ponder (Stibbons) according to the characters present at the time, as it seems unlikely that Sir Pterry would make such a typo (changing both P and O for F and E) and it be missed by the editors. However, I suppose it is possible that he had a different name for Ponder at one point and missed this one.
Does anyone know the real story?

Interestingly, in the copy on Google Books, it's also Fender; https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Lords_and_Ladies/aGlgn73w7TUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Ridcully+sighed+and,+to%22&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover

"unlikely that Sir Pterry would make such a typo": is that typo intentional (in which case, kudos!) or not (in which case, nice coincidence!)?

@terdon Intentional. I believe that he used the name on the group Usenet alt.fan/pratchett (AFP): From LSpace.org "--- WHY PTERRY? ---
Pterry is an affectionate nickname in the tradition of his book
Pyramids. Pteppic, Ptracy and therefore Pterry.

That could be an optical character recognition error if they scanned a manuscript or earlier book, which was then not spotted by proof readers, if any.

It's surprising how many publishers resort to OCR scanning when republishing books from 1980s and 1990s. One would assume the text was available in a digital format already, but perhaps they just weren't good at archiving or lost access to some old storage formats.

My UK Corgi paperback (0-552-13891-6) from 1995 has the scene on page 114, and it is Ponder that is amazed by the sudden production of the coin bag.
Given the page number discrepancy, and the error itself, it seems that the later print was typeset afresh.
The process of typesetting and printing has gone through many changes over the last 45 years - various software and file formats have fallen by the wayside - and it may well be that what had once been fixed in an earlier print sneaked through again, especially if they went to the original file (quite likely an unformatted text file given it would have been about 1990/91) that Pterry submitted.
It's also possible that the error was introduced when the newer print was typeset. I seem to recall Pterry complaining about some international publishers introducing errors and other things (like a full page advert for soup! in the middle of his book).
Apparently, Gollancz and Corgi made several prints before my paperback - it would be interesting to see if the error was in an earlier print (or any other ones for that matter).

I have a 1994 print of the same book, I have the same page number and the same text as you. It seems like the typo was a later issue. Likely an auto correct\spell checker error when the book was re-issued as you suggested.

Early Discworld editions may have even been manual, not digital, although the final typesetting was probably digital. Also, some American publishers tend to insist on American spelling, which can introduce errors.

If you think an ad for another author's book is bad... A German edition of one of the early Discworld books included a soup ad! Pterry was furious.

@PM2Ring ah, yes - it was soup not another book - i'd misremembered the story when I wrote the answer last night. Thanks.

These were obnoxious "product placement" style ads.  Star Trek novelist Diane Duane  has some info on her blog. They also did it to her books. Her friend, novelist Peter Morwood discovered the ad in Pyramids while he & Diane were travelling in Germany. He has further info on tumblr

From Diane: Maggi had taken to inserting little soup ads into the plots of books Heyne were publishing. I knew this because they had stuck one into the middle of the German edition of The Romulan Way (a.k.a Die Romulaner.* One minute things are normal on the Bridge… the next minute, Mr. Sulu is wishing he had a nice cup of soup. GOD I wish I was making this up.

It's likely this was part of the inspiration behind CMOT's obnoxious attempts to spruik Harga's in Moving Pictures

@HorusKol Thanks. Good to know other earlier editions don't have it. I guess that Pterry had a different name at some point and, like you mention, the typeset was different so it got missed.

@bob1 The 1st (brief) appearance of Ponder Stibbons was in Moving Pictures. Pterry wasn't too fussed about maintaining perfect continuity in Discworld, (cf the Trousers of Time), but he wasn't in the habit of changing character's names like that.

Ponder -> Fender isn't a likely typing error, but it is a likely OCR error.

The Corgi edition was first printed in 1993 and then reprinted twice in 1994, 1995, and so on. AIUI a reprint would use the same typsetting, so it's fair to assume that the original Corgi from 1993 would not contain the error. (Mine it seems is from 1994, so I can't prove it.)
It would be interesting to see what's in the Gollancz version.

@Robyn Interesting point. Though given the other Corgi editions, I would have thought that they kept the typeset the same, but maybe not?

My copy of the book (USA Harper Collins paperback) has the expected Ponder, not Fender.
I've seen worse errors make it past editors and proofreaders. Wouldn't read too much into it.

Agreed. He's never referred before or since. It's just a typo.

An early paperback edition of "The Lord of the Rings" had a sentence saying "Bilbo" instead of Frodo when describing an incident in Lothlorien.. These things happen.

At least the editor didn't think "famine" was spelled with seven letters.

Thanks. I recall one story (not one of Pratchett's, the author and title escape me) I read where a secondary, but frequently occurring character changed name at some point in the book. Left me with a vague discomfort reading the rest until I figured it out.

@Wastrel When I was a kid we had an audiobook of LotR, read by JRRT himself, in which he misread "Boromir" as "Denethor" at one point.

@G_B: That is interesting! How much of the Lord of the Rings did it include, and who published it? I wonder whether there is a plausible psychological explanation for the slip.

@PJTraill It was the whole of the trilogy (maybe not appendices) - took up a lot of cassettes! In context an understandable mistake: it's a line that refers to "the son of Denethor", [i.e. Boromir] but he reads it as "son of Boromir" instead. [I had the order wrong in my previous comment.] I don't know the publisher, sorry, but there can't have been too many editions narrated by JRRT.
